# Input string was not in correct format error in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a text editor app that has multiple pages in `Xamarin.forms` but when trying to build or run it I get this error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String       str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.CalculateVersionCode(String currentAbi, String versionCodePattern, String versionCodeProperties)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.GenerateCommandLineCommands(String ManifestFile, String currentAbi, String currentResourceOutputFile)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.ProcessManifest(ITaskItem manifestFile)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<ForEachWorker>b__0(Int32 i)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
```

It does not give me the location of the error,it just tells me that it is in the solution and I'm not entirely sure how i could fix the error, or even find where it is.

I made the app in `Xamarin.forms` and is a text editor with an interface allowing you to save and delete your pieces of code.

And help with finding the error or even better solving it would be really appreciated. Sorry for the lack of included code as there is a lot, and I don't actually know the location of the error so I wouldn't know what to show. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change **android:versionCode="1.0"** in Mainfest.xml file to **android:versionCode="1"**

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value of `android:versionCode` in your `Mainfest.xml` file could been parsed into an integer value .

From [Set application version information](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning), we will see

> **versionCode** — A positive integer used as an internal version number.
>   This number is used only to determine whether one version is more
>   recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent
>   versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number
>   is set by the versionName setting, below. The Android system uses the
>   versionCode value to protect against downgrades by preventing users
>   from installing an APK with a lower versionCode than the version
>   currently installed on their device. The value is a positive integer
>   so that other apps can programmatically evaluate it, for example to
>   check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set the value to
>   any positive integer you want, however you should make sure that each
>   successive release of your app uses a greater value. You cannot upload
>   an APK to the Play Store with a versionCode you have already used for
>   a previous version.
>
> Typically, you would release the first version of your app with
>   versionCode set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with each
>   release, regardless of whether the release constitutes a major or
>   minor release. This means that the versionCode value does not
>   necessarily have a strong resemblance to the app release version that
>   is visible to the user (see versionName, below). Apps and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.
>
> Warning: The greatest value Google Play allows for versionCode is
>   2100000000.
>
> **versionName** — A string used as the version number shown to users. This
>   setting can be specified as a raw string or as a reference to a string
>   resource. The value is a string so that you can describe the app
>   version as a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or relative
>   version identifier. The versionName has no purpose other than to be
>   displayed to users.

So, the `versionCode`( or `Version number`) should be a positive integer, which is an internal version number.
And , the Version name in releases can be set what you want as long as it's a string,(e.g. 2.022.ddd.kkkk) .
Of course, We should set the proper version information to make it easier for users to understand.

Comment: @user11813614  If the answer is useful for you, could you please mark it as a answer?